# I am using GreptimeDB and Grafana for analysis. And there are some problems here

Tags: time-series, prometheus, grafana, promql, greptimedb

I am following the official document to setup environment.
using

- grafana 9.5.15
- greptimedb latest
- connect through prometheus plugin

The GreptimeDB Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "system" (
  "host" STRING NULL,
  "ts" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,
  "cpu" DOUBLE NULL,
  "mem" DOUBLE NULL,
  TIME INDEX ("ts"),
  PRIMARY KEY ("host")
)
```

The GreptimeDB current Data:

```
Time   cpu  mem
12345  2000 8000
45467  2000 10000
```

The Grafana Query: `system`

The current result

```
Time   Value
12345  10000
45467  12000
```

And the time series dashboard only have one line.
It look like the data has been auto summed.

The result I want:

```
Time   cpu  mem
12345  2000 8000
45467  2000 10000
```

And the time series dashboard must have two line

- cpu
- mem

Answer (score 0):

The table you created contains multiple fields (`cpu` and `mem`), which are not supported by vanilla Prometheus and the corresponding Grafana plugin. You can use the [extended PromQL](https://docs.greptime.com/user-guide/query-data/promql#multiple-fields) tag `__field__` to write two queries in Grafana:

```
system{__field__="cpu"}

system{__field__="mem"}
```